# Angular dynamic forms created from model

Tags: angular, model, angular7, dynamic-forms

Lets say I already have a model that binds to a table:
user.ts

```
 export class User
 {
     US_Id : number;
     US_Name : string;
     US_DisplayName: string;
 }
```

I am using dynamic forms and create an object like this for User: 
     new TextBox({
      key: 'US_Id',
            label: 'Id',
             required: true,
            order: 1
             }),
new TextBox({
        key: 'US_Name',
        label: 'Name',
        required: true,
        order: 2
      })
etc

Is there a way to transform my actual User model to a dynamic object of this kind and use it in the creation of dynamic forms, instead of rewriting it?